# DocuSign embedded signing polling violation

Tags: docusignapi

I have submitted DocuSign embedded signing app for review in developer account and  below is my review result and it is passed review. why this is not giving polling violation? All these call within 1 min interval.

01/06/2022 17:43    ##  GET /logout

01/06/2022 17:41    ##  GET envelopes/53d3775f3/documents/certificate

01/06/2022 17:41    ##  GET envelopes/53d3775f3/documents/1

01/06/2022 17:41    ##  GET envelopes/53d3775f3/documents

01/06/2022 17:41    ##  POST    envelopes/53d3775f3/views/recipient

01/06/2022 17:41    ##  PUT envelopes/53d3775f3/recipients/2/tabs

01/06/2022 17:41    ##  GET envelopes/53d3775f3/recipients/2/tabs

01/06/2022 17:41    ##  GET envelopes/53d3775f3/recipients

01/06/2022 17:40    ##  GET envelopes/53d3775f3/documents/certificate

01/06/2022 17:40    ##  GET envelopes/53d3775f3/documents/1

01/06/2022 17:40    ##  GET envelopes/53d3775f3/documents

01/06/2022 17:39    ##  POST    envelopes/53d3775f3/views/recipient

01/06/2022 17:39    ##  POST    envelopes/

01/06/2022 17:37    ##  GET envelopes/6cd37ef3-/documents/certificate

01/06/2022 17:37    ##  GET envelopes/6cd37ef3-/documents/1

01/06/2022 17:37    ##  GET envelopes/6cd37ef3-/documents

01/06/2022 17:36    ##  POST    envelopes/6cd37ef3-/views/recipient

01/06/2022 17:36    ##  PUT envelopes/6cd37ef3-/recipients/2/tabs

01/06/2022 17:36    ##  GET envelopes/6cd37ef3-/recipients/2/tabs

01/06/2022 17:36    ##  GET envelopes/6cd37ef3-/recipients

Comment: can you add the verb for each? (GET/POST/PUT etc.)?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the Documents:list API method for the same envelope twice:

```
01/06/2022 17:41 ## GET envelopes/53d3775f3/documents
01/06/2022 17:40 ## GET envelopes/53d3775f3/documents
```

That's not good unless you have a very good reason to do so.

It may be that your PUT or POST calls to the same envelope are resetting the clock.

But you should also follow the [API Guidelines](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/api-guidelines/). You should not make more calls than necessary. For example, you should only create a new recipient and update tabs after the envelope create if the recipient/tabs are dynamic and can't be created as part of the original envelope definition.